# Unable to open debugger port (localhost:8603): java.io.IOException "handshake failed - connection prematurally closed"

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging

Error running Android Debugger (8603):
Unable to open debugger port (localhost:8603): java.io.IOException "handshake failed - connection prematurally closed"

use android studio3.0.1 in mac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tools > Android > Enable ADB Integration

Disable then re-enable.

Good to go! Hope this helps anyone in the future I was doing a full restart until I discovered this temp fix.

Comment: rerun android studio it works well. Or you could refer whether your debugger was not closed on previous attach.

Comment: @RyanChou i think restarting would be much slower than just disable/re-enable

Comment: In the latest version Android studio. I couldn't find the disable/re-enable options. Could you provide some links for me to find the options?

Comment: @RyanChou you are right, maybe try under kotlin the integrations option.. otherwise i have no way of recreating this at the moment

Comment: cant find this in android studio 3.5