# I have a problem running debug android studio Error running 'Android Debugger (-1)': Invalid argument : Argument invalid [port]

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I have a problem running debug android studio as in the picture.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLAkj.jpg)

Comment: please check [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47965034/unable-to-open-debugger-port-localhost8603-java-io-ioexception-handshake-fa) and [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58253626/android-studio-unable-to-open-debugger-port-java-io-ioexception)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem as you. The cause of my problem is that the hosts file has been modified. You can see if the hosts file of your computer has been modified. Restore can solve the problem.

The following is the contents of the hosts file of a mac computer:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost 
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1 localhost
```